# Meta Tags In CSS External Sheets?

Tags: html, css, meta-tags

Can `<meta>` tags go in external CSS sheets, and be linked to with the `<link>` tags used for CSS?

### That is

```
<html>
  <head>

    <!-- From here --> <meta name="description" content="Text"> <!-- From here --> 
  </head>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* To here */ <meta name="description" content="Text"> /* To here */

.just-a-class-name {
      color: green;
    }
```

**Why the down vote?** I consider this well asked.
If you think it can be improved, please suggest how.
Otherwise, please up vote! Thank you.

Comment: meta tags are not styles and can't be put in a stylesheet.

Comment: @unor what was your edit?

Comment: @DaniSpringer.com: Do you wonder about anything in specific? I removed the code markup from "HTML" and "CSS" because these terms are not code. I rephrased the title to make clear what you ask (your version could, for example, mean that you ask about how to specify external stylesheets in meta tags). I removed the "Question:" label because the question mark already makes clear where/what your question is.

Comment: got it @unor thanks. So meta IS code in this case?

Comment: @DaniSpringer.com: If it refers to HTML’s `meta` element (which I think it does), then yes. In the context of HTML and CSS, every "reserved term" (e.g., element names, attribute names, properties, etc.) would be code. For example: "I have an a element." vs. "I have an `a` element."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meta tags are not styles, and therefore **cannot** be put in stylesheets.